# JSON creation in Scala

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am building HTTP service with scala-play. I want to serve the JSON response.
To serve JSON response, I created case classes and created instance of Writes[T] class which is similar to following

```
case class Point(X: Double, Y: Double)

implicit val pointWrites = new Writes[Point] {
  def writes(point: Point) = Json.obj(
    "X" -> point.X,
    "Y" -> point.Y
  )
}
```

I can server response like: `val json = Json.toJson(Point(10, 20))`

I followed above approach from play documentation.

Why do I need to define class and create Writes[T] instance for  serve JSON response.
If I have to create JSON for dozens of classes, do I have to define all classes and create instances for Writes[T]?

I can easily convert any class data to JSON with following method:

```
def getJSON(data: Map[String, String]): JsObject = {
  JsObject(data.map { el => el._1 -> JsString(el._2) })
}
```

All I need do is create Map[String, String] for any class to serve JSON.

Why play documentation recommends to define case class and create instance of Writes[T] to create JSON representation?

Is there any other way to serve create JSON in scala? I want to keep response time minimal so that JSON creation must be lightening fast.

Comment: If all the classes you need can be described as `Map[String,String]` then your solution is fine. But JSON is able to represent a other types: booleans, numbers, arrays, nested objects, etc.

Comment: Also what about nested JSON objects or objects that depend on each other?  I think the main benefit of the Play way of using classes is to define the JSON serialization once and then it can be used in a variety of contexts.

Comment: You probably don't need the writes for everything. It just allows you the ability to make some customizations like changing the name of a member or converting a value into some other type. You could always try converting an object without defining a writes for it and see what you get, then if you need something different add the writes.

Comment: Instead of creating Writes[T] instance, I could do same using Json.writes[T]. Just want to know if it has some performance overhead? I am calling Json.writes only once and using same value for each conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create the Writes instance. Play already have a default formatter for all the regular types (Integer/String/Boolean..)

You just need to write the case class and add an implicit formatter in the companion object.

See json.scala format[A] description from play:

```
/**
   * Creates a Format[T] by resolving case class fields & required implicits at COMPILE-time
   *
   * If any missing implicit is discovered, compiler will break with corresponding error.
   * {{{
   *   import play.api.libs.json.Json
   *
   *   case class User(name: String, age: Int)
   *
   *   implicit val userWrites = Json.format[User]
   *   // macro-compiler replaces Json.format[User] by injecting into compile chain
   *   // the exact code you would write yourself. This is strictly equivalent to:
   *   implicit val userWrites = (
   *      (__ \ 'name).format[String] and
   *      (__ \ 'age).format[Int]
   *   )(User.apply, unlift(User.unapply))
   * }}}
   */
  def format[A] = macro JsMacroImpl.formatImpl[A]
```

Back to your example, you only need:

```
case class Point(X: Double, Y: Double)

object Point{
  implicit val fmtJson = Json.format[Point]
}
```

to get the json text just do:

val json = Point.fmtJson.writes(Point(10, 20)).toString()

will result: json = {"X":10,"Y":20}